# Не могу вывести числа от 20 до 30 через пробел используя шаг 0,5 (20 20,5 21 21,5….) на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста вывести числа от 20 до 30 через пробел используя шаг 0,5 (20 20,5 21 21,5….) на JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Предположительно так:

```js
for (var i=20; i <= 30; i=i+0.5) {
  console.log(i) 
}
```

UPD:
Если нужно именно через пробел, то можно вот так:

```js
let str = '';
for (let i = 20; i <= 30; i=i+0.5) {
  str += i + ' ';
}
console.log(str.trim());
```